# If chametz is batel before Pesach

Tags: chametz-leaven, passover, bitul-batel-null, halacha

If *chametz* can be *batel* before *Pesach*, why don't we buy (before *Pesach*) any commercially produced product with year-round (i.e., not *Pesach*-specific) kosher certification which does not list *chametz* ingredients?

Is this just another case of "Jews are very particular with *kashrus* on *Pesach*, beyond the letter of the law", or is there something more to it? And if the former then is it binding? — although of course [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) for practical *halacha*.

**Update:**

Here's an example to work with, for the sake of argument. Suppose a chocolate has the following listed ingredients: sugar, chocolate, milk, cocoa butter, cocoa (processed with alkali [i.e., "dutched"]), milk fat, lactose, soy lecithin (as an emulsifier), [PGPR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGPR), and artificial flavor.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38754

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70569

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73854

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few reasons that come to mind:

- The taam of chametz may be absorbed in the utensils used to manufacture that product, and likely there will not be shishim to nullify that taam.
- There may be minuscule amounts of chametz that need not be listed on the label or are included in the generic "natural/artificial flavors", but which are significant due to their potency ("l'taama avida").
- The average layman is not knowledgeable enough to discern which innocuous-sounding ingredients are actually grain based.

This is a question all year round: Why do kashrus agencies go through the trouble of kashering facilities and analyzing ingredients, when they could just rely on *bittul* and *aino ben yomo* in many or most cases? The answer (to my knowledge) is as R' Moshe says, that it would be "*mechu'ar hadavar*" (unseemly) to put a halachic imprimatur on such products. So the same logic presumably applies with regard to pesach.

Comment: Perhaps *kashrus* agencies have different concerns than an individual, namely that agencies are certifying a process *lechatchila*, whereas an individual buys a product post-manufacture.

Comment: Who are we kidding, there's definitely enough to nullify the taste or we'd taste it and the factories wouldn't sell it.