# Can you buy juice before Pesach without a Pesach certification?

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, bitul-batel-null

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, 117:1, says that before Pesach, Chametz is batel b'shishim. So for example, a bottle of 100% apple juice, even if it hasn't been certified that you can know 100% sure that there was no contamination, would certainly have no more than such a small and undetectable amount of Chametz. So can you purchase OU (not OU-P) apple juice **prior** to Pesach with only pure apple juice as a listed ingredient such that any possible chametz in it would be batel beshishim?

I would think the answer is yes unless there is a contradictory opinion and we don't hold by Kitzur Shulchan Aruch here, however just I haven't heard of people doing this. It is a significant question for me as organic apple juice doesn't usually have Pesach certification and I don't like other kinds.

Note that this question can extended to comparable products as well such as canned fish.

Also note that juice companies and fisheries don't process leaven bread on their machinery so there should be little to no concern of ta'am or other contamination.

Comment: If it is a significant question for you, you should be sure to ask your personal Rabbi for a final ruling!

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6595/759

Comment: here is the relevant halakhah in Shulhan Arukh/Mishnah Brurah: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=48&hilite=