# Extra chumros on Pesach

Tags: passover, stringency-chumrah

What is the source for keeping so many extra stringencies on Pesach, so much more so than during the rest of the year?

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38754/being-meticulous-regarding-the-laws-pesach-vs-eating-cheilev

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.

Comment: Chametz is an איסור כרת

Comment: My best guess (as mentioned by @Sye510) is that if one is found with chomeitz in his possession during Pesach, he is liable for kareis. We don't want to take this punishment lightly.

Comment: @ezra Posession of chametz is (only) a *lav*. It’s *eating* it that incurs *karet*.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok It really needs some clarification from the OP. If his question is regarding *eating* Chametz then you would be correct. If his question is regarding *owning* Chametz, then it’s not a dupe at all.