# Is Frank's hot sauce kosher for passover?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover

Is Frank's hot sauce kosher for passover? I just called up the French's food company and they said that the vinegar they use is derived from corn, so it is not חמץ גמור, but it is kitniyos.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6595

Answer (score 4):

If it's *kitniyos* then it's definitely not customarily kosher-for-passover for Ashkenazi Jews who refrain from eating *kitniyos* on Passover. However, even those who do eat *kitniyos* on Passover generally only do so with a reliable kosher-for-passover certification since there's generally not assumed to be any guarantee otherwise that there are no *chametz* ingredients as well. Similarly, there's no guarantee that the utensils and machinery used in its processing were *chametz*-free at the time. (In addition, there is what to discuss regarding the reliability of the customer service representative, from a *halachik* standpoint, regarding whether the vinegar might also have been derived from *chametz* sources.)

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6597