# Is arak kosher for pesach without a specific P hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, passover, hechsher-certification, liquor-beer

I have a bottle of The Spirit of Jaffa [Arak](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/arak_%28drink%29) (ערק הניחוחות של יפו) with a regular circle-K hechsher as well as hashgachat-badatz-yerushalayim.

Is there any reason this shouldn't be kosher for passover without a specific K-P?

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6595

Comment: The anise in arak is added later in the process after the initial distillation. The base alcohol is generally grape based (making arak no different than adding anise seeds to grape distilled vodka), but nothing would prevent them from using cheaper grain alcohol. I'd be concerned.