# Items not labeled Kosher for Passover

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, passover, hechsher-certification

What halachic concern(s) are there with items which are 100% non chametz and do not contain chametz (e.g. olive oil - or for that matter avocado, cottonseed and whatever other types of oils, pure cranberry juice etc.) but do not bear a ‘Kosher for Passover’ certification?

P.S. Admittedly I’m more curious about follow up questions and gaining clarity on the whole topic. For now, a general answer will do but hopefully comments can be moved to a chat to further discussion.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6595/759

Comment: I'm almost certain we have a general "why do we need a certification for X", but can't seem to find it now. The general answer for these types of questions is our foods are complicated, so without a valid Hechsher we're taking a shot in the dark.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you!!

Comment: @DoubleAA Should I delete the question?

Comment: Try to search for related questions and close this as a duplicate if you find questions with good answers. That way people searching in a similar way would be able to find answers. Note that many hechsherim will be able to put a list of those items that are kosher for Pesach with or without specific lables. For example, I have found a number of Apple Juice brands that require OU-P and others that are valid without the specific Kosher for Pesach lable. Just reading the lables or descriptions one can often not tell the difference.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate of the earlier question, but your comments here, Oliver, imply that you think it is, so I've closed this as a duplicate. If I misunderstood, please let me know.